# VSphere cannot free up unused space

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere

Currently there are Drivers on Vms that have a lot of unused space. I tried to edit the settings and reduce the number of unallocated space and the space that is free. However, The value that I am typing does not get stay when I click Okay it changes back to the old value. Example: I changed 450Gb to 240. But when I click okay it reverts back to 450GB. Going back to the computer management, I do indeed see that it is not even using 240GB. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't shrink a vmdk in the manner that you're trying. One method you can use is to run a P2V/V2V of the virtual machine and "shrink" the vmdk during the P2V/V2V by specifying a smaller size during the P2V/V2V wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to shrink the disk. Change the disk from 450GB to 240GB and boot from gparted. You can then shrink the disk to 240GB.